# Can windows reboot command shutdown /r /t 0 link to command reboot?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, reboot

I know we can reboot windows with `shutdown /r /t 0` command, but is there any way to restart just running `reboot` on Run?

Comment: Create the `reboot.bat` file with proper command(s) and place it into any folder which presents in PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a .bat script containing the command(shutdown -r -t 0), save it as reboot.bat and then place it somewhere suitable on your system. If the location is not already in PATH, add it to PATH using the command below. This will work when using it in CMD. For use with RUN, see grawity's comment below.

```
set PATH = %PATH%;C:/Directory/Where/You/Saved
```

Comment: You can skip the latter part and use your "user profile" folder `C:\Users\lcsncm` – it works because it's the "current folder" as far as Explorer is concerned, so it gets checked even before %PATH%.

Comment: However, I don't think your example command will do much good. Environment variables of a child process (CMD) don't automatically propagate to the parent process (Explorer). To actually update %PATH% such that it would work with _Run_, you would need to set it in the registry to be applied at logon time.

Comment: Yes, I can see the issue. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've created a bat file with following lines 
`@echo off 
shutdown /r /t 0`
And placed in
`%windir%/system32/reboot.bat` 
didn't add the path. I've tested with Run and command prompt, working fine
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo shutdown /r /t 0 > reboot.cmd
reboot
```